# Ubuntu 18.04.3 losing email and internet connection but not SSH

Tags: networking, ssh, firefox, thunderbird

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.3 using the KDE desktop.
System used to work flawlessly until about 2 weeks ago. Now, I regularly (maybe 2-3 times an hour) lose email and Internet connection from Thunderbird and Firefox **but I am logged in to a remote server via an SSH tunnel at the same time and that connection stays active**.

Trying to ping google.com from the command line shows 100% package loss, so this is not a problem specific to Firefox and Thunderbird. 
Disconnecting the WiFi and re-connecting solves the problem but when I do this I sometimes loose my SSH tunnel, which causes data loss.
I'm not sure where to even start looking for the problem. Any hint welcome!

Comment: When you `ping google.com` at such a time, does it give a correct IP address on the first line, such as `PING google.com (172.217.168.238) 56(84) bytes of data.`? Just to make sure that this isn't an DNS problem.

Comment: Smells like a possible router problem. Try simply power-cycling the router.

Comment: @user535733 but if it was a router problem, why would I then stay connected to my SSH tunnel? IN addition, the network manager claims I am still connected to the network.

Comment: @Jos I pinged using the IP address directly and lost all packages, so I assume that it is not a DNS issue.

Comment: So, if you can confirm that the SSH tunnel is still working, you should be able to do `nc -v server port` to the SSH server (default port is 21) and get a response, right?

Comment: @Jos I can try this next time it goes down but I know that the tunnel is life because I am working on the command line on the remote server and it is all working (I can run commands remotely) while Email and Internet are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has been a problem caused by an older version of Thunderbird. I have updated Thunderbird and Firefox to the latest versions and I don't seem to have this problem since then. I think the problem is specifically caused by the old version of Thunderbird trying to connect to the imap server at Yahoo. I can't be certain yet that this has solved it but if you are having similar problems, this might be the first thing to try.